# snapd returned status code 400: Bad Request

Tags: linux, ubuntu

ОС Ubuntu 16.04

Хочу установить Atom text editor.
Устанавливаю через "Ubuntu Software".
При нажатии на Install появляется следующая ошибка:
**snapd returned status code 400: Bad Request**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сделайте

```
$ span find atom
$ sudo snap install --classic atom
```

а можете воспользоваться http://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/